# How to validate different data type using same key in joi validation

Tags: node.js, joi

This is my Scenario. I want validate same key but different datatypes passing in `joi validation`. How to achieve this:

**joi validate**

```
    static validateSearchedProduct(request_query) {
        const joiSearchedProductSchema = Joi.object({
            product_category: Joi.objectId()
        })
        return Joi.validate(request_query, joiSearchedProductSchema);
    }
```

**function**

```
validateSearchedProduct({product_category:"5d44258bcb9b611da1f658c8"})
validateSearchedProduct({product_category:["5d44258bcb9b611da1f658c8"]})
```

Answer (score 3):

So, you want `product_category` to be either `string` or `array` of `strings`. Then, you could use [Joi.alternatives](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v16.0.0-rc2/API.md#alternativestryschemas) and do something like that:

```
static validateSearchedProduct(request_query) {
        const joiSearchedProductSchema = Joi.object({
            product_category: Joi.alternatives().try(
              Joi.string(),
              Joi.array().items(Joi.string())
            )
        })
        return Joi.validate(request_query, joiSearchedProductSchema);
    }
```

And `Joi.string()` can be replaced with whatever that is needed (e.g. `Joi.objectId`).